# Wordpress redirect from one directory to another but exclude wp-admin and wp-login.php

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I would like to redirect an entire WordPress sites (posts, pages, categories etc) from one sub directory (blog) to another (news) but excluding `/wp-admin/` directory and the `/wp-login.php` file.

I have tried the following, but that obviously redirects the whole site.

```
RedirectMatch 301 /blog(.*) /news$1
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You could try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login\.php(.*)$
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /news/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Please **edit your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?